# External Hard Disk not showing up

Tags: external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have a samsung external drive 3TB. The device shows up in the device manager but it wont sow up in my list of drives in My computer. I have to remove it and plug it in about 10 times before it shows up. When it does show up, it freezes when I access it and then it again disappears(but still exists in the Device Manager). It is correctly detected in a Linux installation on my friend's PC, but not in any other Windows system. In Linux, it does show that the drive has no device information when i try accessing the SMART info(my disk has SMART  The problem started after I put my computer on Sleep mode and then had to switch off the power supply. Ever since rebooting after that, the disk has become inaccessible. Can anyone  please help me figure out whats happening.

Comment: External hard drives *never* show up in the list of drives in `My Computer`. They're not supposed to do. Imagine how confusing it would be if they did -- say you had a drive with two filesystems on it. If you dragged a file onto it, which filesystem should it go to? If you double-click on it, which should open? The disk itself is only supposed to appear in `Device Manager` and `Disk Management`.

Comment: But a disk with a single partition and single filesystem should show up in the Hard Disk Drives section. How else can anyone open the drive and view the contents ? I am talking about a USB external disk